# Visual Studio 2015: Emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have the following problem, hopefully somebody has a solution.
Previously I had Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013. 
I upgraded to Windows 10. 
I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. 
I created a new solution, with only 1 project for a blank Universal Windows app. I am using C#.

When tring to run my proyect by selecting any of the "Mobile Emulators 10...." I get the following error:
[image]
However, if I select "Simulator" it works. Also, If I open a solution for Windows Phone 8.1 and I run using "Emulator 8.1" it works.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: how much free RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 8GB installed, free is about 4GB when using Visual Studio

Comment: there is also a file missing: rdvgm.exe run sfc or DISM to check for corrupted/Missing files.

Comment: Since it looks like an actual file is missing a Visual Studio repair might be worth an attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is interested, I found a solution that works for me here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/823ce958-5287-40f9-bfc8-8fb6db0d4f95/visual-studio-2015-windows-mobile-10-emulator-app-deployment-failed-error?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Basically the is what people should do:

- 1) Start the app deployment process in VS 2015 by selecting an
  emulator and then pressing F5
- 2) Wait till the emulator starts and shows "OS is starting"
- 3) Then, go to the task manager, go to the
  process of VS 2015 (devenv.exe) and kill it

Result: The emulator image is being built and the app deployment process cannot fail as VS is not running anymore.

As soon as the emulator is fully built and you can see Windows Mobile 10 in action, close the emulator and start the app deployment process through VS 2015 again. This time, the app deployment process will succeed.

Comment: I have exactly the same error, but this method doesn't help. Error still the same. Even after reinstalling graphics driver.

Comment: As I commented in the other possible solution. For me, the proposed answer solved the issue. It seems that the error message might be for different reasons so it is impossible to give a single solution that works for all.

Comment: This an old post but I am having the same problem running a virtual machine with W10. I have tried recommendations mentioned here but it's not helping. Does anyone have more ideas?

Comment: This was the solution for me

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue however I'm using VMWare Fusion to run Windows 8.1. The steps in this article solved my problem.
https://blogs.endjin.com/2013/06/running-the-windows-phone-emulator-in-vmware-fusion/

---

> 1. Stop the virtual machine that you are running the emulator on.
> 2. Open the *Virtual Machine Library* <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (`Windows`→`Virtual Machine Library`)
> 3. Select the VM in the list and go to `Settings`→`Processors & Memory`→`Advanced Options`
>
>    Tick the `Enable hypervisor applications in this virtual machine` checkbox to enable nested virtualization. This will add `vhv.enable = "TRUE"` in the VM configuration file (more on that below).
> 4. Go back to the VMs list and right-click on the VM and select `Show in Finder`.
> 5. In the Finder window, right-click and `Show Package Contents`.
> 6. Once the content (list of files and folders) is displayed, find the VMware virtual machine configuration file – the file with the *.vmx* extension.
> 7. Open this file in TextEdit and add this line at the end: `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"`
> 8. Save and restart the VM.

Comment: Is there any permanent solution to this. This happens to me very frequently and is getting on my nerve.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem trying to run HoloLens emulator. I had to go into Hyper V manager, and go into Hyper-V settings. Select the Physical GPUs and Uncheck the box "Use this GPU with RemoteFX" .

The rdvgm.exe pertains to this. Turning that option off resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved : I too faced same issue. In my case the problem was I have not enabled the developer mode. After enabling it perfectly worked fine.

Comment: One more possible solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your "Virtual Switch" information under: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections? If not, you can try to recreate your "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" again from Hyper-V to see if that resolves your issue. Try these steps below:

1.) Open Hyper-V

2.) Shutdown any existing configured Phone emulators.

3.) Click on "Virtual Switch Manager"

4.) Click on the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"

5.) Remember what the settings are displayed there (because you will delete it and recreate it)

6.) Delete the existing "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking "Remove"

7.) Click "Apply" and "OK"

8.) Re-create the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking the "New virtual network switch" and use the same settings you remembered in Step 5.

9.) Then try to F5 from Visual Studio - which should configure a new emulator on the right virtual switch.

10.) Now the error will be solved. if not in hyper v start the emulator of windows phone -> then click Connect (Now the emulator start's from hyper v)

11.) Then try to F5 from Visual Studio - which should start the emulator (took some time to start up in my case)

Comment: I tried step by step but not luck, same error appears.

Comment: try this solution from Microsoft :[Not enough memory error message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2911380)  . I didn't mention this before because you have 8GB ram installed . This solution is recommended for ones that have fewer than 8 GB of RAM installed. You should try this solution. I did perform the steps from the link as I only have 4GB of RAM installed

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I tried but still does not work. I'm getting the same error.
I also uninstalled and installed again the emulators "Windows 10 for Mobile image" but did not help.

Comment: For me, the proposed answer solved the issue. It seems that the error message might be for different reasons so it is impossible to give a single solution that works for all.